# How to get pcm data buffers from MediaCodec output buffers?

Tags: c++, android-ndk, audio-streaming, wav, android-mediacodec

I want to decode mp3 file to pcm or wav data.(Android Application: API 20)

I use [this](https://dpsm.wordpress.com/2012/07/28/android-mediacodec-decoded/) approach for decoding data from mp3, but on native platform with C++.

After decoding i know from decoder filled output buffered data is in "sound/raw" format. 
This buffered data stored in uint8_t*, so it`s uint8_t(byte) array (values from 0 - 255).

How can i convert this arrays into pcm or wav format, if it is possible?

Answer (score 1):

The audio decoders currently all return 16 bit PCM audio, so just cast your `uint8_t*` to `int16_t*`, which allows you to read out the PCM samples. If you have `size` bytes of data, you can read `size/2` samples from the `int16_t*` pointer. You also might want to check `AMEDIAFORMAT_KEY_CHANNEL_COUNT` from the output format - if you have `size/2` samples in total you'll have `size/(2*channels)` tuples of samples for each channel.

Comment: maybe for casting better use "byte shift" like this        "    
 int16 intValue = (byte[1] << 8) | byte[0]   "?